# React Native local video with RN asset system

Tags: react-native

I used `react-native-cli` to bootstrap a new app on RN [`0.31`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.31.0) for cross-platform development with iOS and Android. My app has one image and one video asset under a `src` directory at the project root, as illustrated here:

```
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── assets
    │   ├── images
    │   │   └── radio.png
    │   └── video
    │       └── turntable.mp4
    └── components
        ├── App.js
        └── BackgroundVideo.js
```

I'm loading the video using a [new feature in `react-native-video`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/pull/251) that allows for MP4 asset resolving using the RN asset system. Here's how I'm including my video file:

```
<Video
  repeat
  resizeMode='cover'
  source={require('../assets/video/turntable.mp4')}
  style={styles.backgroundVideo}
/>
```

For Android, both the image and the video are automatically copied from `src/assets` to the `resourcesDirRelease` configured in `build.gradle` when I [generate the release APK](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/signed-apk-android.html#generating-the-release-apk). The image works fine. But for some reason I cannot get the video to display when built using the release APK.

Any ideas on a debugging approach that *does not* introduce a custom `react-native bundle` command into my workflow? Here's the [source code needed to reproduce](https://git.habd.as/comfusion/lumpen-radio/src/branch/master) the problem.

Comment: Is the video working in debug mode? I recently had a similar problem and the problem was movie resolution. Max 480p was displaying on Android.

Comment: Same problem, did you find an answer? Work fine in debug, fails on release

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. The project is on hold for the time being. My next step was to try Radek's suggestion, unless other's were presented. Please keep us informed if you find something. Good luck!

Comment: Its working in debug, but nothing seems to work for me in build release. Neither resolution of 480p, or anything else.